# Always position a div inside a div on the bottom right with a minimum margin

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I currently want to create a page in which I have a div with two columns. One column is used for a navigation, the right column is used for content.

Now, in the right column I want to display some action button at the bottom right and I want it to always be in the bottom right. However, it can either be that the left column has a greater height than the right column and vice versa, but both boxes shall always be the same height (flex) and the action buttons shall always be at the bottom right.

Here's an example HTML and CSS (Codepen: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eyRrwx)

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="left">
    <ul>
      <li>These items are dynamic
      <li>meaning there can be a number of N of them
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    THIS IS DYNAMIC CONTENT, THAT CAN CHANGE IN HEIGHT
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; right: 0px;">
      <button>TEST</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.content {
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.left li {
  height: 50px;
}
.right {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #a9a9a9;
  float: left;
}
```

As you can see, I have two columns, same height, left one is longer, so the right column gets bigger through flex, etc.

The problem I'm having now is the following. When the right column has more text than the left one I have this problem:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="left">
    <ul>
      <li>These items are dynamic
      <li>meaning there can be a number of N of them
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    THIS IS DYNAMIC CONTENT, THAT CAN CHANGE IN HEIGHT<br>
    THIS IS DYNAMIC CONTENT, THAT CAN CHANGE IN HEIGHT<br>
    THIS IS DYNAMIC CONTENT, THAT CAN CHANGE IN HEIGHT<br>
    THIS IS DYNAMIC CONTENT, THAT CAN CHANGE IN HEIGHT<br>
    THIS IS DYNAMIC CONTENT, THAT CAN CHANGE IN HEIGHT<br>
    THIS IS DYNAMIC CONTENT, THAT CAN CHANGE IN HEIGHT<br>
    THIS IS DYNAMIC CONTENT, THAT CAN CHANGE IN HEIGHT<br>
    THIS IS DYNAMIC CONTENT, THAT CAN CHANGE IN HEIGHT<br>
    THIS IS DYNAMIC CONTENT, THAT CAN CHANGE IN HEIGHT<br>
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; right: 0px;">
      <button>TEST</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.content {
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.left li {
  height: 50px;
}
.right {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #a9a9a9;
  float: left;
}
```

or as Codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/goRKpx

As you can see, the text goes OVER the button. Is there any possibility to to always align the action button on the bottom right, but also always have a minimum margin to the text above?

Comment: Why don't you set the button to `position:absolute` and position it on the bottom right ?

Comment: Is there any work around to solve this? I mean, I can't be the first person to try this out, right?

Comment: You can't use `position:absolute` and not expect some overlap. What is the intended result?

Comment: @Paulie_D The intended result is that I have two columns, and the right column has text and multiple buttons that are always on the bottom right and that there's a minimum margin of like 30px to the content above.

Comment: @woulduracler How does it differ if I set the button to `position:absoloute; right: 0` or the div? The problem (as seen in the 2nd codepen) would be the same.

Comment: What about `padding-bottom: 40px;` for the right div? That gives internal padding for your buttons so they won't overlap with your text. And this won't grow the div when the left box is taller.

Comment: What about this [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WdOyJ](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WdOyJL) ? You can add as much content as you want and the button is always in the bottom right corner.

Comment: Both solutions seem to work. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Apply flexbox to the `.right` div then set the `margin-top` to `auto` on the button wrapping div and it will always be at the bottom of the right div regardless of content height.

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.left li {
  height: 50px;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #a9a9a9;
}

.button-wrap {
  margin: 1em;
  margin-top: auto;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left">
    <ul>
      <li>These items are dynamic
        <li>meaning there can be a number of N of them
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    THIS IS DYNAMIC CONTENT, THAT CAN CHANGE IN HEIGHT<br>

    <div class="button-wrap">
      <button>TEST</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Shorter content:

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  position: relative;
}

.left li {
  height: 50px;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #a9a9a9;
}

.button-wrap {
  margin: 1em;
  margin-top: auto;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left">
    <ul>
      <li>These items are dynamic
        <li>meaning there can be a number of N of them
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    THIS IS DYNAMIC CONTENT, THAT CAN CHANGE IN HEIGHT<br>


    <div class="button-wrap">
      <button>TEST</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```